# How to use 2D vector in this scenario?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a text file that contains these data and the data is be dynamic it can be more or less than 5 columns.

```
5:346:87:131:1:
4:463:57:152:8:
7:345:77:121:5:
```

i want to use 2D vectors so that i can get output like this from the vector:

```
cout<<BData[0][0]<<endl; i will get 5
cout<<BData[1][0]<<endl; i will get 4
cout<<BData[2][2]<<endl; i will get 77
```

how can i get my 2D vector to get this results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > BData;

// split inputs and load the container

// use your code...

cout<<BData[0][0]<<endl; // i will get 5
cout<<BData[1][0]<<endl; // i will get 4
cout<<BData[2][2]<<endl; // i will get 77
```

Read [How to split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c) for information on how to split strings in C++

Comment: sorry if im not clear, i want to know how to use the vector to get these results, as im pretty clear on how to split them

Comment: @user2625464 - an STD `Vector` has an interface somehow similar to an `array`, so `[]` is accessing a specific index within it. if the `vector` is well initialized, it acts as an `array`

Comment: @user2625464 - if my answer helped you - kindly approve it. thanks